# Launch Android app with custom Google Now command

Tags: android, android-intent, google-now

I've taken a look at some other questions, but never saw the answer I was looking for. I can make an activity to receive system intents, such as incoming messages. Google Now intents like AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM can also be received by the app. How can I set up my app to receive a *custom* Google Now voice command? For example, in Google Now I want to say
Ok Google, [App name] [input data].
Then the app would be launched and would have the [input data] to handle. This can be accomplished with Tasker and AutoVoice, but how can I make my Android app listen for *any* Google Now command on its own?

Comment: Hello..did you found any way to do it...??

Answer (score -2):

You can covert the voice to text. You can create a service or Broadcastrecevier to detect the voice input and do appropriate actions.

Covert voice to text link: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: In that example the user has to manually open the app and click on a button to trigger speech recognition. I was asking how to have the app listen for a custom command without having to open the app. Sort of like latching on to Google Now's listener.